# How to make JSF validator, valueChangeListener and actionListener be called once but not multiple times when binding and View scope are used

Tags: jsf-2

The JSF component uses `binding` and backing bean is of `View scope`. The component have `validator` and `valueChangeListener` set. And when component's value is changed partial request is sent to server. And `validator` and `valueChangListener` are called many times but not once within request.

How to make them to be called once during request?

If remove `binding` the methods are called correctly once.

But is it possible to do not remove binding and make listeners be called once?

Sample of used code is next:

```
<h:inputText id="txt"
             validator="#{myBean.validateValue}"
             valueChangeListener="#{myBean.valueChanged}"
             binding="#{myBean.txtInput}">
   <f:ajax event="valueChange"
           execute="@this"
           render="@this"/>
</h:inputText>

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class MyBean {

private HtmlInputText txtInput;

public void valueChanged(ValueChangeEvent ve) {
    ...
}

public void validateValue(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    ...
}

public HtmlTextInput getTxtInput() {
    return txtInput;
}

public void setTxtInput(HtmlTextInput txtInput) {
    this.txtInput = txtInput;
}    

}
```

The same issue takes place for `actionListener` and `commandLink` component if it uses binding and backing bean has `View scope`.

Comment: Using `binding` is [**wrong**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used) here. You should elaborate the functional requirement for which you incorrectly thought that using `binding` is the right solution. Only this way we can answer the right way to achieve the functional requirement.

Answer (score -1):

The possible solution could be just to override class which is used by `UIInput` and `UICommand` to store `validators` and `listeners`. The class is `javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder`.

This class straightforward add new `listener` to  backing list not checking if the same `listener` already is there.
Thus the solution is to check if `listener` exists and not to add it then.

So take `javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder` from `jsf-api-2.1.<x>-sources.jar` and add it to your project to the corresponding package. Replace method `add` with such one:

```
void add(T attachedObject) {
    boolean addAttachedObject = true;

    if (attachedObject instanceof MethodExpressionActionListener
        || attachedObject instanceof MethodExpressionValueChangeListener
        || attachedObject instanceof MethodExpressionValidator) {

        if (attachedObjects.size() > 0) {
            StateHolder listener = (StateHolder) attachedObject;
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            Object[] state = (Object[]) listener.saveState(context);
            Class<? extends StateHolder> listenerClass = listener.getClass();

            for (Object tempAttachedObject : attachedObjects) {
                if (listenerClass.isAssignableFrom(tempAttachedObject.getClass())) {
                    Object[] tempState = (Object[]) ((StateHolder) tempAttachedObject).saveState(context);
                    if (((MethodExpression) state[0]).getExpressionString().equals(((MethodExpression)tempState[0]).getExpressionString())) {
                        addAttachedObject = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    clearInitialState();
    if (addAttachedObject) {
        attachedObjects.add(attachedObject);
    }
}
```

After that validators, valueChangeListeners and actionListeners will be triggered only once even when component binding and "View", "Session" or "Application" scopes are used.

Comment: To future readers of this "answer", noted should be that the OP is being very naive and ignorant and that this approach will **still** cause major trouble when multiple different users concurrently use the page with the declared component.

Comment: above comment of @BalusC is fully nonsense. No changes to concurrency of internal listenres list are made in the code. Even more the approach is tested with a big application and perfomance became better comparing with multiple calls for the same listeners and validators within one request.